The result of Kotlin suspend fun cannot be received from @AfterReturning in spring boot 3.2.x version
After calling the suspend func, we are post-processing the response (ex logging,...) through @AfterReturning.
Until spring boot version 3.1.12, we were able to receive and process returning value as desired.
However, when we upgraded the version to 3.2.x (and even 3.3.x), an issue occurred where MonoOnErrorResume was returned as a returning value.
@AfterReturning("execution(* x.x.x.suspendFun(..))", returning = "response")
fun controllerSuccessLogging(joinPoint: JoinPoint, response: Any) {
    logger.info("$response")
}

exmaple)
boot 3.1.12
[2024-06-20 14:34:46,181] [INFO] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [RequestLoggingAspect] API [/v1/resource/test] PARAMS [GetTestRequest(abc=123)]
[2024-06-20 14:34:46,184] [INFO] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [MySQLExceptionHandleAspect] [SQL] info(statement=query.selResource.selectInfo parameter={abc=23} )
[2024-06-20 14:34:46,288] [INFO] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [RequestLoggingAspect] GetTestResponse(result=ok) <-- works as intended

boot 3.2.5
[2024-06-20 14:31:52,967] [INFO] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [RequestLoggingAspect] API [/v1/resource/test] PARAMS [GetTestRequest(abc=123)]
[2024-06-20 14:31:52,968] [INFO] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [RequestLoggingAspect] MonoOnErrorResume  <-- issue 
[2024-06-20 14:31:52,991] [INFO] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [MySQLExceptionHandleAspect] [SQL] info(statement=query.selResource.selectInfo parameter={abc=23} )

Are there any changes to usage, or are there any parts where support has ended?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Ideally, link to a Maven project on GitHub. You cannot expect community members here to create an application from scratch and insert your mini code snippet into it.  Reproducibility is key to getting spot-on answers quickly (or any helpful answers at all). Thank you.
